# Measurements for thermal diffusivity of graphene?

Tags: experimental-physics, thermal-conductivity, graphene, data

We have known for a long time that graphene has in-plane thermal conductivity ranging between 2000 and 4000 $W m^{-1} K^{-1}$. But in order to model heat transport on a sheet of graphene, we need more than the conductivity: we also need specific heat in order to obtain the thermal diffusivity that is used in the equation.

I couldn't find any measurement results online for this quantity. I've only seen some crude estimates based on phonon transport, but even so, no specific figures.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this article](http://poplab.stanford.edu/pdfs/PopVarshneyRoy-GrapheneThermal-MRSbull12.pdf), the molar heat capacities of graphite and graphene should be identical above roughly 100 Kelvin. The heat capacity of graphene is dominated by phonon contributions above roughly 1 Kelvin (below that, free electron heat capacity becomes a significant contributor).

The molar [heat capacity of graphite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity#Table_of_specific_heat_capacities) at room temperature is $8.53\text{ J mol}^{-1}\text{K}^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

1- Lin H, Xu S, Wang X, Mei N 2013 Nanotechnology 24 415706.
2- H. Cabrera et al Thermal diffusivity of few-layers graphene measured by an all-optical method
(forthcoming paper) J. Phys. D: Appl. Phys.: http://iopscience.iop.org/0022-3727/page/Forthcoming%20articles;jsessionid=9DEA4B129430EB2B3EB18BBC27C4B940.c1

Comment: Please consider adding the relevant numbers from the paper, link only answers are discouraged at physics.SE. (Although you obviously answer quite correctly, which asks for a resource online).

Answer (score 0):

here you are about thermal diffusivity of graphene measured with a non contact method
http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0022-3727/48/46/465501

Although single layer graphene exhibits a very high
thermal diffusivity, this parameter can be significantly reduced
in the presence of additional layers, approaching eventually the
value of bulk graphite, for example thermal diffusivities were calculated
as D = (6.5 ± 0.09) × 10−4 m2 s−1, D = (1.9 ± 0.07) × 10−4
m2 s−1 and D = (1.3 ± 0.05) × 10−4 m2 s−1 for four, eight and
sixteen graphene layers respectively.
For more details see
http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0022-3727/48/46/465501

and an additional confirmation of these results can be found in a recently published article with very similar results

The defect level and ideal thermal conductivity of
graphene uncovered by residual thermal reffusivity
at the 0 K limit